# Add a full width header item to a Grid View in AbsListView (Xamarin)

Tags: android, listview, gridview, xamarin, customization

I have a list in my app, and it's implemented as an AbsListView, so that when we are working on a smaller screen (phone) it's a List and when we are on a larger screen (tablet) it's a Grid.
All works well.

Now I want to add in a header item which is completely different from the regular items on my list - it has a completely different xml file. It's always the first item in the list.

I've added in code to my Adapter class like so:

```
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        SavedInfo subViews = null;
        var rowView = convertView;
        var channel = items[position];

        // don't want to reuse if our previous view was a header
        if (rowView?.Tag != null)
        {
            subViews = rowView.Tag as SavedInfo;
        }

        // try to put in a different view if there is a header shown
        // special id value for header is -1
        if (position == 0)
        {
            subViews = null;
        }

        if (subViews == null)
        {
            if (position == 0)
            {
                rowView = context.Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.header_layout, null);

                // Do setup stuff with this layout
                rowView.Tag = null;
                return rowView;
            }

            rowView = context.Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(cellLayout, null);

            // Do stuff with regular layout, take savedInfo from Tag
            rowView.Tag = subViews;
        }

        // other adjustments to the regular layout

        return rowView;
    }
```

So that's fine in a regular list - I have one header item and lots of regular items. However, when I switch to GridView (which uses the same adapter) my "header" item is now just the first cell in the grid.

What I *want* it to be is more or less the same as it is in the list view - a single column which fills the width of the screen, then followed by the regular grid. The point is I want an item which fills all the columns across, but scrolls up with the grid. Is there a way to do this? I understand I might need to replace with some sort of custom Adapter View. Does anyone have an example of code doing a grid with one item filling multiple grid columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is not possible - the recommended way to put in a header is to use a CoordinatorLayout and a CollapsingToolbarLayout while changing the ListView to a RecyclerView